# PEAR HTML_Quick Form Functions And Processing Data

Tags: php, mysql, pear

I have the following code wich is a form for user registration generated by PEAR's html-Quick Form:

```
 <html>
<head></head>
<body>
     <?php

     require_once "HTML/QuickForm.php";
    $form = new HTML_QuickForm('UserRegistration', 'POST');

      //Form elements***********************************************
        form->addElement('header', 'RegistrationHeader', 'Fill in your details');
    $form->addElement('text', 'firstname', 'First Name', array('size' => 49, 'maxlength'=>49));      
    $form->addElement('text', 'lastname', 'Last Name', array('size' => 49, 'maxlength'=>49));
    $form->addElement('text', 'username', 'Username',array('size'=> 49, 'maxlength'=>49));
     $form->addElement('password', 'password', 'Password', array('size' => 30, 'maxlength'=>30));
      $form->addElement('password', 'confirmpassword', 'Confirm Password', array('size'=> 30, 'maxlength'=>30));
       $form->addElement('text', 'email', 'Email', array('size'=> 49, 'maxlength'=>49));
        $form->addElement('text', 'confirmemail', 'Confirm Email', array('size'=>49, 'maxlength'=>49));
        $form->addElement('hidden', 'ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
      $buttons[] = &HTML_QuickForm::createElement('reset', 'null', 'Clear');
      $buttons[] = &HTML_QuickForm::createElement('submit', 'null', 'Submit');
      $form->addGroup($buttons, null, null, '&nbsp;');

      //***********************************************************************************************************

      //Setting of form functions*************************************************
      //Email DNS check function
      function checkEmailDNS($email, $domainCheck = false)
    {
    if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+\@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+'.
                   '\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/', $email)) {
        if ($domainCheck && function_exists('checkdnsrr')) {
            list (, $domain)  = explode('@', $email);
            if (checkdnsrr($domain, 'MX') || checkdnsrr($domain, 'A')) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
    }
    $form->registerRule('checkmailDNS', 'callback', 'checkEmailDNS');
       //******************************************************************************************
       //Check for Email existance in the DataBase
       function checkEmailfromDB($value) 
    {
      try {

       $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mytestsite;host=localhost', 'root', '');

    } catch (PDOException $e) {

       die('ERROR: Cannot connect: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    $value = $pdo->quote($value);

    $sql = "SELECT userID FROM users WHERE userEMail= $value;";

    $ret = $pdo->query($sql) or die('ERROR: ' . implode(':', $pdo->errorInfo()));

    $str = $ret->fetchColumn();

    $flag = ($str == false) ? true : false;

    unset($pdo);

    return $flag;        
      }
       //*******************************************************************
        //****************Check for username existance in the DataBase
       function checkusernamefromDB($value) 
        {
        try {

       $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mytestsite;host=localhost', 'root', '');

    } catch (PDOException $e) {

       die('ERROR: Cannot connect: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    $value = $pdo->quote($value);

    $sql = "SELECT userID FROM users WHERE userName= $value;";

    $ret = $pdo->query($sql) or die('ERROR: ' . implode(':', $pdo->errorInfo()));

    $str = $ret->fetchColumn();

    $flag = ($str == false) ? true : false;

    unset($pdo);

    return $flag;        
      }
        //**************************************************
    //Form   Rules********************************************
      $form->addRule('firstname', 'Your  First name is required', 'required');
      $form->addRule('lastname', 'Your Last name is required', 'required');
       $form->addRule('username', 'Username is required', 'required');                 
       $form->addRule('úsername', 'Username is already in use, choose a different one', 'callback', 'checkusernamefromDB');    
         $form->addRule('password', 'Error: Enter a password', 'required');
      $form->addRule('password', 'Error: The password should be at least 6 characters long', 'rangelength', array(6,30));
       $form->addRule('confirmpassword', 'Error: Password confirmation is required', 'required');
       $form->addRule('confirmpassword', 'Error: The password should be at least 6 characters long', 'rangelength', array(6,30));
       $form->addRule(array('password','confirmpassword'), 'ERROR: Password mismatch', 'compare');
      $form->addRule('email', 'Emal is required', 'required');
      $form->addRule('email', 'Enter a valid Email adress', 'email');
      $form->addRule('email', 'Email is incorrect', 'checkmailDNS', true);
      $form->addRule('email','Email is already in use on the system', 'callback', 'checkEmailfromDB'); 
      $form->addRule('confirmemail','Email confirmation is required','required');
      $form->addRule('confirmemail', 'Email is incorrect', 'checkmailDNS', true);
      $form->addRule('email','Email is already in use on the system', 'callback', 'checkEmailfromDB'); 
      $form->addRule(array('email', 'confirmemail'), 'Error: Email mismatch', 'compare');
      //***********************************************************************************************************

      //Form Filters*********************************************************************************************
      $form->applyFilter('_ALL_', 'trim');
       $form->applyFilter('firstname', 'lettersonly');
       $form->applyFilter('firstname', 'strtolower');
        $form->applyFilter('firstname', 'ucfirst');  
         $form->applyFilter('lastname', 'lettersonly');
         $form->applyFilter('lastname', 'strtolower');
          $form->applyFilter('lastname', 'ucfirst');
       $form->applyFilter('email', 'strtolower');                
        $form->applyFilter('confirmemail', 'strtolower');

      //Display Form************************************************************
       if ($form->validate()) {

          $form->freeze();
      }
      $form->display();  
    ?>                                                                                                               

</body>
</html>
```

What are the correct ways to check if a value already exists in the database display a message if it does, you know-as a validation rule, and the big deal-what is the way to process the data and insert it to the database? I'm pretty new to PHP and even more so to PEAR, I've seen some manuals but they don't seem to show how the submited data is handled afterwords, probably too newbie of a thing...:D

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that by few different ways, for example:

(1) PEAR DataObject:

```
if ($form->validate()) {
   $user = new DataObjects_User;
   $user->username = $form->exportValue('username');
   if($user->find()) {
      // username is already exists in the db
   }

}
```

(2) PDO

```
if ($form->validate()) {
    $username = $form->exportValue('username');
    $email = $form->exportValue('password');

    if( !checkusernamefromDB($username) or !checkEmailfromDB($email) ) {
       $form->display(); 
    } else {
       $sql = "INSERT INTO users (userID,userEMail) VALUES($username, $email)";
       $pdo->query($sql);
    }

}
```

I hope the above examples will give an idea how to check if a value already exists in the database. There is a very good tutorial how to use PEAR HTML_QuickForm: http://devzone.zend.com/1165/generating-and-validating-web-forms-with-pear-html_quickform-part-2/

Comment: Vasil, thank you for your answer, how are those two examples inmplemented into the form I've posted codewise, are those PEAR packages to be installed and the second question is how to insert the data in the database after validation? I'm new to php as you've most certanly noticed. By the way, are you from Bulgaria?;)

Comment: If you don't have installed MDB2, you can install it from the command line. Also you need to install the driver of the appropriate DBMS to have a working installation:

$ pear install MDB2
$ pear install MDB2#mysql

After that you should check the MDB2 documentation here: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.php

Comment: Vasil, OK, става ли накратко да ми обясниш как да интегрирам във вече споменатата форма функция, която да проверява MySQL базата данни за дублираща се стойност, като информира user-а за това, ако такава стойност е налична, друго-как да вкарам вече попълнените данни от user-а в базата данни.

Comment: Примерите, които съм ти дал по-горе би трябвало да работят, виждам обаче, че не използваш PEAR DataObjects, затова преминаваме на вариант 2 - MDB2. Инсталацията става много просто като изпълниш следния ред в терминал: "$pear install MDB2", след което библотеката е на твое разположение. В линка, който съм ти дал по-горе има детайлна информация как да извличаш или добавяш данни. Трябва също така да отбележа, че за да ползваш PEAR трябва да имаш добри познания по native php. Още нещо, PEAR вече е заменен от много мощни MVC Frameworks, и по тази причина се използва все по-рядко.

Comment: По принцип методът fetchRow() връща integer ако открие резултат, в противен случай връща NULL.